# Mock Response returns undefined for async testing in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing

I am trying to get the a mock response for my HTTP call, but for some reason the mock response returns as undefined.

Here is my unit testing code in Jasmine:

```
  it('should fetch a single user by an id key',
   async(inject([UserService], (userService) => {

    const mockResponse = {
      id: 1,
      username: "dtrinh100"
    };

     mockBackend.connections.subscribe(
       (connection: MockConnection) => {

         // make sure the URL is correct
         expect(connection.request.url).toEqual("http://localhost:3000/api/users/1");
         connection.mockRespond(
           new Response(
             new ResponseOptions({
               body: JSON.stringify(mockResponse)
             }))
         );
       }
     );

     userService.getUser(1).then((user) => {
         console.log(user); // user is undefined
         //expect(user["id"]).toBe(1);

       });

})));
```

Here is my original userService code for UserService:

```
private usersUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/users';
getUser(id: number): Promise<User> {
    const url = `${this.usersUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json().data as User)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

I think the userService code is correct and the issue seems to be with my unit testing mock response. How do I get the mock response to return the proper object?

Comment: where are you injecting MockBackend?

Comment: @Jonnysai The MockBackend is created in the beforeEach function.

Comment: You try to read the `response.json().data` so I think it should be `JSON.stringify({data: mockResponse})` in the `mockRespond` function.